# Wifi keeps reconnecting

Tags: networking, drivers, lenovo, atheros, ath9k

My wifi keep getting reconnected every 1-20 minutes, 
 I tried every solution I've found online.
I tried adding "options ath9k nohwcrypt=1" to /etc/modprobe.d/ath9k.conf and It didn't worked. 
I tried changing the `iw reg` to `IL` but it doesn't work (and after reboot it gets back to GB altough I set it inside `/etc/default/crda`). 
And I found these lines in `dmesg` again and again.
Laptop: Lenovo G510. 
Ubuntu: 16.10.
Kernel: 4.8.0-37-generic. 
Network card: Qualcomm Atheros AR9485. 
Driver: ath9k.
lshw results: http://pastebin.com/v01PB0ay 
dmesg: http://pastebin.com/QFWNgef3 
kern.log: http://pastebin.com/WS69kh85 
lsmod: http://pastebin.com/v490i65G 
"iwconfig; iwlist scan | egrep -i 'ssid|cipher'": http://pastebin.com/ETtydDLm

any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: Please edit the question to include results for `iwconfig; iwlist scan | egrep -i 'ssid|cipher'`

Comment: @Jeremy31 added.